# I can't install the multitouch driver if I do `sudo apt-get install xf86-input-multitouch`

Tags: 11.10, touchpad, trackpad

I am running Ubuntu 11.10 and have added the mactel ppa but I can't install `sudo apt-get install xf86-input-multitouch`

I have done this:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mactel-support && sudo apt-get update

expecting this to work:
http://bitmath.org/code/multitouch/

I can't find the multitouch driver anywhere!

#### Update

After using the first answer by Scott Stookey I get this: I guess I will open another question as to how to revert to the stable Ubuntu packages...

Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 xserver-xorg-input-multitouch : Depends: xorg-input-abi-12
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input this at the command line.

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-multitouch
```

This holds the Multitouch X input driver

Comment: Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 xserver-xorg-input-multitouch : Depends: xorg-input-abi-12
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.